# How to get PHP array values in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a PHP script that sends this array to the client via ajax:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $209.90
    [1] => $20.99
    [2] => $188.91
)
```

I am sending the array to the client this way:

```
return $servicePrices;
```

I have this jQuery statement:

```
success: function(data) {
  //console.log('Success'+data);
  $( '#tourSubtotal' ).val( data[0] );
  $( '#tourDiscount' ).val( data[1] );
  $( '#tourTotal' ).val( data[2] );
},
```

My results for each ID value are `A`, `r` and `r`. Instead, how can I get the 3 currency data values from the array in my ajax jQuery?

Comment: Did you parse your PHP array into a JSON object or something like that?

Comment: How are you sending these to the client?

Comment: See my amended OQ @MasivuyeCokile on how I send the array from PHP to jQuery -- thanks.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Based on my answer, would you like to post the full code of PHP and I can help you design your end-point to make changes. Or you wanna take it from my answer and give me a shout if you are stuck or something.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are using `print_r()` function to display this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $209.90
    [1] => $20.99
    [2] => $188.91
)
```

In that format it's just as useful as any *string* is. You have to use `json_encode()` to convert it to a format both languages understand like:

```
["$209.90", "$20.99", "$188.91"]
```

Your PHP code should be something like:

```
<?php
  $json = some_value;
  // Remove this:
  // print_r($json);
  // Instead, write this:
  echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

And then you can use it in JavaScript, the way you have specified. Also, jQuery is smart enough to understand that the response is JSON and you don't need `JSON.parse()` in most of the cases.

Comment: I've added the "string" part to try to clearify that like that it's not an array, but a string

Comment: "jQuery is smart enough to understand that the response is JSON" - if the server is well-behaved and sets correct Content-Type header, or the client forces `dataType` or uses `$.getJSON`. If no such hints are present, jQuery should opt for safety and do no extra processing.

Comment: @Amadan Yep, agreed. `:D`

Answer (score 3):

You can return the array in a JSON encoded format from PHP as mentioned below:

```
$result = array(
    '0' => '$209.90'
    '1' => '$20.99'
    '2' => '$188.91'
);
return json_encode($result);
```

And on the AJAX success function you can use :

```
success: function(data) {
   var temp = JSON.parse(data);
   $( '#tourSubtotal' ).val( temp[0] );
   $( '#tourDiscount' ).val( temp[1] );
   $( '#tourTotal' ).val( temp[2] );
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With the right MIME type and/or jQuery `$.ajax` option `dataType`, you don't actually need `JSON.parse`, jQuery does it for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly @Kishen Nagaraju !! Thanks !